# Is there a pandas method to filter one column based off the value in another column

Tags: pandas, filtering

Is there a pandas method to filter one column based off the value in another column?

I have a table of patient visits and I want to see the time between their first visit and their second visit, but only for new clients. To find new patients I have to find all the patients that have a visit type of "intake". In code, I need to mark all patient ids with true if there is an intake in their visit type list. Currently I first create a list of patients who've had an intake and then I create a mask that checks if each patient is in that list. But I'm wondering if there's a single method or better way in general that I can use to do that on the original dataframe.

Current Method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
"VisitType": ["Regular Session", "Regular Session", "Regular Session", "Intake", "Regular Session", "Intake", "Regular Session", "Regular Session", "Regular Session", "Regular Session", "Regular Session"]})
# create new Patient List
newPatientList = list(df.loc[df['VisitType'] == "Intake", 'ClientID'])
# check if patient in new patient list
mask = df['ClientID'].map(lambda id: True if id in newPatientList else False)
# filter dataframe
df = df[mask].copy()
```

Input:

| ClientID | VisitType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Regular Session |
| 1 | Regular Session |
| 1 | Regular Session |
| 2 | Intake |
| 2 | Regular Session |
| 3 | Intake |
| 3 | Regular Session |
| 3 | Regular Session |
| 4 | Regular Session |
| 4 | Regular Session |
| 4 | Regular Session |

Desired Output from One Line of Code:

| ClientID | VisitType |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Intake |
| 2 | Regular Session |
| 3 | Intake |
| 3 | Regular Session |
| 3 | Regular Session |

Answer (score 2):

You could make a series of client ids

```
df[df["VisitType"]=="Intake"].ClientID
```

and filter the original dataframe by id's that are in that series.

```
df[df.ClientID.isin(df[df["VisitType"]=="Intake"].ClientID)]
```

Comment: Seems to run slower than my code?

Comment: For a big dataframe, this is easily the fastest solution. See my answer with timings.

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems like an interesting problem, I ran `timeit` over all the answers, including OP's original code, using this dataframe of 1,000,000 rows with 200,000 random `ClientID` values and a 1 in 100 chance of `VisitType == Intake`:

```
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000),
    "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) 
})
```

The results were as follows:

| Name | Algorithm | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ziying35 | filter (any) | 26.05 |
| Nick | transform/max | 0.098 |
| Nick | cummax | 0.104 |
| tdelaney | isin | 0.050 |
| OP | map | 93.82 |
| ombk | isin | 0.381 |

As can be seen, @tdelaney answer is about 2x faster than the next 2 solutions proposed by @Nick. @ombk's answer (a more complicated version of @tdelaney) is about 4x slower again, and @ziying35 and OPs solutions were more than 500x slower than @tdelaney solution.

Full testing code:

```
timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000), "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) })
''', stmt='''
out = df.groupby("ClientID").filter(lambda g: g['VisitType'].eq("Intake").any())
''', number=1)

timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000), "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) })
''', stmt='''
out = df[(df['VisitType'] == 'Intake').groupby(df['ClientID']).transform(max)]
''', number=1)

timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000), "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) })
''', stmt='''
out = df[(df['VisitType'] == 'Intake').groupby(df['ClientID']).cummax()]
''', number=1)

timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000), "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) })
''', stmt='''
out = df[df.ClientID.isin(df[df["VisitType"]=="Intake"].ClientID)]
''', number=1)

timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000), "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) })
''', stmt='''
newPatientList = list(df.loc[df['VisitType'] == "Intake", 'ClientID'])
out = df[df['ClientID'].map(lambda id: id in newPatientList)]
''', number=1)

timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed('filtering')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID":random.choices(range(200_000), k=1_000_000), "VisitType": random.choices(["Regular Session", "Intake"], cum_weights=[99,100], k=1_000_000) })
''', stmt='''
out = df[df["ClientID"].isin(df[df["VisitType"].str.lower().str.contains("intake")]["ClientID"].unique())]
''', number=1)
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort. So im bumping it.

Answer (score 1):

The funniest one liner. I could simplify it and still make it work. But here ya go
my brains after 10hours of work.

So I groupby clientID and sum all the words of VisitType; sum of strings is like concatenating strings without spaces.

```
df[df["ClientID"].isin(df.groupby("ClientID",as_index=False).sum().query('VisitType.str.contains("Intake")')["ClientID"].tolist())]
```

This is a much cleaner version.

```
df[df["ClientID"].isin(df[df["VisitType"].str.lower().str.contains("intake")]["ClientID"].unique())]
```

###### nested queries

```
df.query(f"""ClientID in {df.query("VisitType.str.contains('Intake')")["ClientID"].to_list()}""")
```

Comment: This is really just a more complicated (but also more robust) version of tdelaney answer. As a result it's somewhat slower. See my answer with timings.

Comment: @Nick i totally agree! Very unoptimized. Especially the use of query is an optimization killer!

Comment: It is a huge improvement over OPs code though, and it is the only solution that wil work if the strings are not all in the same case.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df.groupby("ClientID").filter(lambda g: g['VisitType'].eq("Intake").any())
>>>
   ClientID        VisitType
3         2           Intake
4         2  Regular Session
5         3           Intake
6         3  Regular Session
7         3  Regular Session
```

Comment: For a big dataframe, this is very slow. See my answer with timings.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test the different approaches and sharing the timing results with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use create a mask where `VisitType == 'Intake'`, groupby `ClientID` and then use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max` to broadcast the mask to all rows with the same `ClientID` value:

```
mask = (df['VisitType'] == 'Intake').groupby(df['ClientID']).transform(max)
out = df[mask]
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   ClientID        VisitType
3         2           Intake
4         2  Regular Session
5         3           Intake
6         3  Regular Session
7         3  Regular Session
```

Note that if `Intake` is always the first `VisitType` for a client, you can simply use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) instead:

```
mask = (df['VisitType'] == 'Intake').groupby(df['ClientID']).cummax()
```